# My nested for loops are taking so much time while calculating term-frequency

Tags: python, list, for-loop, tf-idf

i have a list "total_vocabulary" with all the unique words in a collection of 56 documents. There is another list of list with words of every document "rest_doc". I want to calculate term frequency of each word from "total_vocabulary" in "rest_doc" so "term_freq" list will be a list of list of the same size of total_vocabulary and at each index of term_freq will be a list of size 56 representing the total occurrence of each word in each document. The problem is that the nested for loops are taking so much time,almost a minute to run. is there any way to do it faster?
code:

```
for i in range(len(total_vocabulary)):
    doc = []
    for j in range(len(rest_doc)):
        counter = 0
        for k in range(len(rest_doc[j])):
            if total_vocabulary[i] == rest_doc[j][k]:
                counter = counter + 1
        doc.append(counter)
    term_freq.append(doc)
```

here is my code.

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating over the words in each document many times -- once per each word in `total_vocabulary`.

It would be much faster if you iterated over the words in each document just *once*, and you can do that by rearranging the loop and also making `total_vocabulary` into a *set* instead of a *list*, as set lookups are much faster.

```
vocab_set = set(total_vocabulary)
for document in documents:
    for word in document:
        if word in vocab_set:
            counter = counter + 1
```

Comment: My main problem is iterating through list of lists of all documents. for example if a word is "believe", then it will have different results of it if it is repeated in different document. I need the term frequency of every word in total_vocabulary in all the documents where the total occurrence of that word in each document is separated.  This is not getting the job done. sorry

Comment: Your question said that the problem was speed, and I addressed that in my answer.  If my answer is unsuitable due to unstated requirements on your part, that's on you.

Comment: Your answer doesnt calculate term frequency correctly, what will i do with speed if my output is incorrect.